# Sublime Text Autoformat code without node.js?

Tags: formatting, sublimetext3

Does anyone know if there is a plugin that i'm overlooking? I've tried several plugins and nothing has worked.

Comment: Which ones have you tried? And why don't you want to use node?

Comment: I was hoping to not to have to install node on my work pc as i'm quite sure they wouldn't approve. I tried Sublime-HTMLPrettify,  sublimetext-codeformatter, and one other one I cannot think of the name of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tried Sublime-HTMLPrettify I assume you're trying to reindent HTML. The only plugin I could find on Package Control that didn't seem to require Node is [HTMLBeautify](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/HTMLBeautify). For some reason it's listed as ST2-compatible only, but a (very) quick scan of the code didn't reveal anything that wouldn't work with Python 3, so you should be able to install it manually and get it to work. Unfortunately it only indents using tabs, but a little bit of hacking on the code could easily change that to spaces if you wanted to.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest remapping the built-in shortcut of ST3 for reindenting whole blocks of code.
 See this link for details:
https://github.com/chrisg86/sublimetext-tips#reindent-whole-blocks-of-code

All you have to do then is select your desired block of code and hit the shortcut.
Hope this helps!